# Getting a string's length and allocating memory at the same time?

Tags: c

I was asked to do the following:

1. Print "Enter an integer and string"
2. Scan the integer and string

The integer in this case represent's the string's length (I can assume correctness of input). The thing is, I cannot figure out how to both recieve a length and then allocate memory for the string of that length and then insert the string I recieve the pointer I've created all in the same line. 
I would appreciate any help!

Comment: why does it have to be one line?

Comment: I apologize for bring unclear. The one line refers to the fact that the user will enter "<int> <string>" in this one line, and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the data is entered all in one line, you don't have to read it all at the same time:

```
scanf("%d",&length);
str = malloc(length+1);
scanf("%s",str);
```

Each time use use scanf, it just reads as much as it can, and leaves the rest in the input buffer.

Comment: don't have a c compiler with me right now, but won't this take input in the format <int><newline><string>?

Comment: @mfrankli: `%d` will read an integer, and stop when it hits anything that is not part of the integer, like the whitespace between the integer and the string.

Comment: @mfrankli `"%d%s"` --> <white-space><int><white-space><non-white-space-string>

Comment: "it just reads as much as it can"
Notice that when working with strings, `scanf()` stops reading the input when a space is entered.

Answer (score 1):

simply sample. check omit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int len;
    char *string;
    printf("Enter an integer and string :");
    scanf("%d", &len);
    string = malloc(len+1);
    scanf("%*[ \t\n]");
    fgets(string, len+1, stdin);//scanf(" %[^\n]", string);
    printf("%s.\n", string);
    free(string);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With POSIX 2008 or GNU [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) (but not on Mac OS X), you could do it all on one line with the `m` (memory allocation) modifier:

```
char *str;
int   len;

if (scanf("%d %ms", &len, &str) != 2)
    …Oops; something went wrong…
…use len and str…
free(str);
```

With this usage, the fact that the integer is the length of the string is immaterial; they're unrelated data items as far as `scanf()` is concerned.